# Issues restoring database with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm making a backup of a PostgreSQL 14 database from a remote server and restoring in another remote server. I'm using windows 10.

The backup:

```
pg_dump -h 10.10.10.10 -U postgres -Fc mydbname > myfilename
```

I also tried making the backup like this:

```
pg_dump -h 10.10.10.10 -U postgres --format=c mydbname > myfilename
```

And to restore:

```
pg_restore -h 10.10.10.10 -U postgres --clean -d mydbname < myfilename
```

I get this error: pg_restore: error: `input file does not appear to be a valid archive`

I also tried:

```
pg_restore --format=c -h 10.10.10.10 -U postgres --clean -d mydbname < myfilename
```

Error: `pg_restore: error: did not find magic string in file header`

I've been looking for this and tried all the answers to similar questions I could find here on Stackoverflow, none solved the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I try to avoid redirects on Windows, as they can create encoding/line ending issues.  Use the -f option on pg_dump, and with pg_restore you can specify the filename as the last argument with no preceding `<`.

Comment: What was version of Postgres you dumped from? Also what version of `pg_dump` did you use to do the dump? You can use newer versions of `pg_dump` to dump older Postgres versions and then restore to newer Postgres version. It does not work the other way around.

Comment: I agree with jjanes: redirecting outputs and inputs can lead to problems on Windows. Use `pg_dump .... -f myfilename` and `pg_restore .... myfilename` instead

Answer (score 1):

The comment made by JJanes is right. For windows the commands would be like this, on power shell:

```
pg_dump -h 10.10.10.10 -U postgres -Fc --dbname=mydb-file=myfile

pg_restore -h 10.10.10.10 -U postgres --clean --dbname=mydb myfile
```